# Where does Laravel store throttle data?

Tags: php, laravel, throttling, laravel-6.2

I use Laravel rate limit (throttle). I wonder where it stores throttle data and how I can change the default storage system to MySQL/Mariadb or Redis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel uses its [cache](https://laravel.com/docs/master/cache) service to store throttle data. The cache configuration is located at `config/cache.php`.

You can change your default cache driver to `"redis"` or `"database"` (default is `"file"`). Take a look at its documentation for full instructions: https://laravel.com/docs/master/cache